# Tap0 not receiving traffic

Tags: linux, routing, tcpdump, tap, policy-routing

I have created a tap device tap0 address 10.2.1.4 and added it to a host bridge br1 with address 10.2.1.1

I have "nc 10.2.1.4 -l 1234" running on the host and from another machine I do a "nc 10.2.1.4 1234".

tcpdump -i tap0 doesn't show any of the traffic. The traffic is shows up when I do "tcpdump -i br1"

What do I have to do to make the traffic showup on tap0.

Comment: interface inserted in a bridge shouldn't have ip address, because bridge works at the layer 2

Answer (score 1):

Usually bridged interface can not be an endpoint receiving traffic and directing it up to protocol stack of host machine. As soon as a bridge is added it is responsible for this sort of work itself.

FYI:  http://www.microhowto.info/howto/bridge_traffic_between_two_or_more_ethernet_interfaces_on_linux.html#idp24240

Tap is a special logical interface which is represented and accessible internally. Hint: remove tap0 from the bridge and it will remain to be accessible from other hosts.

Thus, datapath is: Network -> eth0 -> br1 -> Stack TCP/IP -> Application

You can see traffic on tap0 if:

- It is broadcast.
- It is routed, say tap0 is used in a tunnel or VM connection.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to force `tap0` to recieve its own IP packets, you may use `ebtables`. When packets are `DROP`ed in the ethernet layer of `tap0` at `broute` table, these packets go into the the IP layer of `tap0` instead of `eth0`. See also: http://ebtables.sourceforge.net/examples/real.html#example1

If you just want more addresses for your host, use `ip address add ...`.