# Forwarding ethernet frames to tap interface using ebtables / ebtables missing broute table

Tags: iptables, linux-networking, ebtables

I spend much time today figuring out how to do this, but I could not find a solution. In my mind it should be possible. I'm trying to setup the following setup:

[setup overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wk8nJ.png)

Reading the `tap1` interface and forwarding to `enp0s3` using Go **should** work without any problems... I hope. If I do a `ping 10.0.0.10 -I tap1` I can see the ether frames in the Go application. (I currently use https://github.com/songgao/water but I will probably migrate to https://github.com/mdlayher/packet if I get this to work)

The problem I have is forwarding the etherframes from `enp0s8` to the `tap1` interface. I have tried multiple commands but it does not work. I tried using `iptables`:

`iptables -A FORWARD -i enp0s8 -o tap1 -j ACCEPT` and similar commands.

I then found this question: [Tap0 not receiving traffic](https://serverfault.com/questions/554477/tap0-not-receiving-traffic) where Sherwood Wang said the following:

```
If you want to force tap0 to recieve its own IP packets, you may use ebtables. When packets are DROPed in the ethernet layer of tap0 at broute table, these packets go into the the IP layer of tap0 instead of eth0. See also: http://ebtables.sourceforge.net/examples/real.html#example1
```

What sounds exactly what I need. I think I found the command he means here: https://ebtables.netfilter.org/examples/basic.html#ex_brouter

`ebtables -t broute -A BROUTING -p ipv4 -i tap1 --ip-dst 172.16.1.1 -j DROP`

However I get the following error: `ebtables: No chain/target/match by that name`. If I look at `man ebtables` I don't see the `broute` table mentioned. I do see it here though https://linux.die.net/man/8/ebtables. So am I missing something?

I also tried `ebtables -A FORWARD -i enp0s8 -o tap1 -j ACCEPT` from https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-networking-3/ebtables-to-setup-forwarding-and-ethernet-level-nat-4175538316/ but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a few months, you may or may not still be having this issue, or others may stumble across this post in the future. I ran into this same situation. it appears that broute isn't built into the current version of ebtables. use the command ebtables-legacy with the same options (i am using accept as opposed to drop) it will add the rule to the broute table and function as expected